# Forms of Parvati/Durga that depict her riding a wolf

Tags: puranas, tantra, devi, durga, parvati

Agni Purana, in 'Describing the Characteristics of An Idol of Devi Parvati' says the following:-

> 10b-13. (In the worship of the manifest form of the goddess) (the
> goddess should be worshipped) as manifest with two eyes, the syllable
> oṃ (containing the three letters), pure and being present with (lord)
> Śaṅkara (Śiva). Two lotus seats (should be provided). (She may be
> endowed) with two arms or four arms. **She may be riding a lion or
> wolf** or have eight or eighteen hands. (She may be wearing) a garland
> and rosary beads. (She may wear) a bunch of lotuses on the neck. She
> may be holding an arrow or bow with the right hand and a book,
> betel-leaf, club, offering protection and a kamaṇḍalu (waterpot) with
> the left hand. One should place in each one of these (hands) Gaṇeśa,
> mirror and an arrow.

- [Agni Purana, Chapter 326](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083556.html)

In several Iconographies of the Mother Goddess, I have seen her Riding a Lion or A Tiger but never a Wolf. This leads me to the Question: Do any Puranas or Tantras describe any form of hers where her iconography is depicted as Riding a wolf? Or perhaps any Shilpa Shastras? A citation would be much appreciated.